# Code 4004 in C# silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, runtime-error

I'm currently having problem in my project. I'm having Code 4004 error in silverlight application. I don't know what I did wrong. Here are the image link.

http://s1100.photobucket.com/user/Fredi_Tansari/media/errorInsilverlight.png.html

here are the codes. After the the invalideoperation exception it goes to the unhandled exception error.

```
    private void getstatusCompleted(LoadOperation<PatientStatus1> obj)
    {
        try
        {
            PatientStatus1 bc = obj.Entities.First();
            if (bc != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Patient has a status already, please use update instead new");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inserting new Patient status");
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            PatientStatus1 newPatientStatus = new PatientStatus1();
            newPatientStatus.ColorCodeID = "1";
            newPatientStatus.timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            newPatientStatus.UserID = "Jimmi";
            newPatientStatus.Patient_PatientID = Convert.ToInt32(patientIDTextBox.Text);
            newPatientStatus.MasterPatientStatus_masterPatientStatusId = Convert.ToInt32(masterPatientStatusIdTextBox.Text);
            newPatientStatus.MasterLocation_masterLocationID = Convert.ToInt32(masterLocationIDTextBox1.Text);
            patientstatusDomainContext.PatientStatus1s.Add(newPatientStatus);
            patientstatusDomainContext.SubmitChanges();

        }



    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why are you putting object creation code in your catch-block? Can't you prevent invalidoperationexceptions from happening instead of catching it? And which code of line causes the next exception?

Comment: Hi there Djerry, after the patientdomaincontext.submitchanges(); I'm seriously stumped right now. I just want to check if the data already exist in the database or not when I decided to use the try-catch, feel free to suggest better way to do it.

Comment: I guess you're using entity framework, so I won't suggest work methods as I'm not that familiar. What you can do now is put a try-catch around the line that generates the error (you can remove this try catch later when you've found what causes this). The errors SL throw are sometimes confusing, so see what the error tells you.

Comment: i'll try to do that.. I'll post the result as soon as i'm done

Comment: @djerry, I tried to put the try catch, I think this has to do with the domain service operation issue.The entire operation is actually performed and then it goes to the exception.

Comment: can you edit your post and give the message from the exception? It's more than likely that something simple is causing this (see this example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/49eedba6-417f-465a-995d-20742dbb8708/). But to find out, we need to know what the exact message is (caught in the try-catch).

Comment: @Djerry, after careful debugging, I forgotten to insert a value into a no-null field, that's why when I tried to use the try-catch it doesn't shows any error message. Apparently the error is in the server side. It's a stupid mistake, Thanks for your time mate.

Comment: No problem, this is a typical SL problem, errors on the server are nasty to debug. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this key value to 1.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings\JITDebug